# @media query is not supporting in IE 8

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have applied @media query in my website to make it responsive according screen resolution but however it's not working whereas earlier, it was working fine.

I am sharing page code below. please someone help me out here that why my code is getting failed.

```
<link href="header.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="indexcss.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->       
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/icon.jpg">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
```

Comment: in addition to answers that have already been posted: [MDN compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#Browser_compatibility) for media queries

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, media queries are not supported in IE8.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are not supported in IE8, you'd need to use a pollyfill to patch the functionality for older browsers (if you must support them)

One option is to use use [respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to get media queries working in IE8

Another approach to using a pollyfill is to look at [gracefully degrading](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/) and providing acceptable functionality for olderbrowser rather then pollyfill.

Remember that older browser are likley also the worst performing (compared to modern browsers) and it's also possible that they are running on older hardware.

Adding pollyfills to already under performing browser would degrade the experience for the users.

Answer (score 0):

See the piece of [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#respond-file-proto) from Bootsrap

> Due to browser security rules, Respond.js doesn't work with pages
>   viewed via the file:// protocol (like when opening a local HTML file).
>   To test responsive features in IE8, view your pages over HTTP(S). See
>   the [Respond.js docs](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/README.md#support--caveats) for details.